# How to factor out conditional log checks in Java 8 & SLF4J?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I am trying to factor out `if (log.isInfoEnabled())` or `if (log.isWarnEnabled())` statements so I am thinking to create an interface in **Java 8** like below however I am not sure if I could run into any problems?

```
public interface Logging {

    Logger log_ = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getClass());

    default void logInfo(String... messages) {
        if (log_.isInfoEnabled()) {
            String meg = String.join("log message: ", messages)
            log_.info(msg);
        }
    }
}


public class Hello implements Logging {

    //Imagine this function is called lot of times like imagine
    // an infinite loop calling this function
    public void doSomething(String name) {
        if (name.equals("hello")) {
            logInfo("What class name does the log print here ? ")  
        }
    }

     //Imagine this function is called lot of times like imagine
    // an infinite loop calling this function
   public void doSomething2(String name) {
        if (name.equals("hello2")) {
            logInfo("What class name does the log print here ? ")  
        }
    }

    //Imagine this function is called lot of times like imagine
    // an infinite loop calling this function
    public void doSomething3(String name) {
        if (name.equals("hello3")) {
            logInfo("What class name does the log print here ? ")  
        }
    }
}
```

vs

```
public class Hello {

    Logger log_ = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Hello.class);

    public void doSomething(String name) {
        if (name.equals("hello")) {
            if (log_.isInfoEnabled()) { // Don't want to have this code everywhere
                logInfo("What class name does the log print here ? ") 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Are these two equivalent? Any problems if I go with the Logging interface above?

Comment: This isn't going to work.  Interfaces can't have fields, other than constants.

Comment: If you don't declare anything it is indeed a static final right. Other words the log_ is indeed a constant.

Comment: Constant value will only be evaluated once at the beginning of the program, so `log_` in the interface will always have a constant class not matter where you call it from. BTW `Thread.curren...` doesn't give you the correct class, you will need to use StackTrace to get correct class.

Comment: +11thdimension Any suugestion on how to implement something close to what I am doing? I can use Classes however it wont be very useful since you can only extend one other class

Comment: @user1870400 Why do you want to "factor out" `isInfoEnabled()` calls? Keep in mind that the logging methods has an internal check if the message should be logged or not, depending on the current logging configuration.

Comment: You did not say what version of Java you are using. There is some new syntax in Java 8 that you may use here.@Progman It makes sense to have logging level checks if you need to do some expensive operation to create the string to be logged.

Comment: Can't you use an abstract class instead?

Comment: @shmosel I answered this is my previous comment but I will say it again. If I create an abstract class then other classes cannot extend any other class besides the Logging class which would be a huge limitation. Having an interface would be seamless

Comment: @Progman Please take a look at this one https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/internal/Logging.scala This is something Apache Spark uses and it is one of the most popular projects in the industry

Comment: What they do in that snippet of Spark is entirely unnecessary, and only adds additional overhead. Popular not necessarily means that it doesn't have bad code or too much cargo cult.

Comment: @user1870400 Your answer doesn't explain why you want to "factor out" the `isInfoEnabled()` calls. Please explain why you want to remove them and why you don't do it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to factor out if (log.isInfoEnabled()) or if
>   (log.isWarnEnabled()) statements

I think you didn't understand how and why the `if (log.isLevelXXXEnabled()){...}`  pattern  is used.

What you are writing here :

```
public void doSomething(String name) {
    if (name.equals("hello")) {
        if (log_.isInfoEnabled()) { // Don't want to have this code everywhere
            logInfo("What class name does the log print here ? ") 
        }
    }
}
```

has really no need to be enclosed by :

```
if (log_.isInfoEnabled()){
```

Why ?
 Because you pass a `String` to log that doesn't require any computation : `"What class name does the log print here ?"` to your logger.
Besides, loggers are already designed to write the log only if the actual level of the logger matches with the requested log level.

Now, suppose you passed an object with a expensive `toString()` method.
The logger invokes indeed the `toString()` method of the passed object to log **when it performs actually the log**.
But in this case, using a check before logging is still useless.

Suppose `myObject` is a variable referring to an instance of class with a `toString()` performing multiple computations or simply a collection of objects.
This is helpless :

```
if (log_.isInfoEnabled()) { 
    logInfo(myObject); 
}
```

as the logger implementation will perform `myObject.toString()` only if the effective log level of the logger matches with the requested level for logging.

Using this check log pattern makes sense only when you have to perform a relatively expensive computation for the passed object.
Generally, it is when you perform yourself a computation and you provide it as parameter to the log operation.
For example :

```
if (log_.isInfoEnabled()) { 
    log_.info("name :" + myPerson.getName() + ", order history :" + myPerson.getOrders()); 
}
```

Here it makes sense not because you spare 4 concatenations but because `myPerson.getOrders()` is a collection with potential hundreds elements and invoking `toString()` on it should be done only if you really log.

Now how do you think design a generic method that could do this specific check and any other specific check for you ?
It is not possible.
In fact, what you try to do is possible but will only repeat what the logger libraries already do for you.
The specific case where you should do the check because it is expensive has to be performed by you for each specific case.

Now according to preferences, you can of course replace this :

```
if (log_.isInfoEnabled()) { 
    log_.info("name :" + myPerson.getName() + ", order history :" + myPerson.getOrders()); 
}
```

by this other syntax :

```
log_.info("name : {}, order history : {}", myPerson.getName(), myPerson.getOrders());
```

that relies on the

```
public void info(String format, Object... arguments);
```

method of the `org.slf4j.Logger` class.

Using `if (log_.isInfoEnabled()) {`  or `public void info(String format, Object... arguments);`  doesn't change really the problem as you should always think when using the way to spare potential computation.

Comment: I realize many people are talking about the fact that  I am not avoid string concatenation therefore I have edited my question so I can keep it the core of my problem.

Comment: I don't have any database variables or long lists that has lot of items however my doSomething function above is called gazillion times every second (Imagine an infinite loop calling my doSomething function above)

Comment: When you write `if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {`, in fact, it is not really faster. Checking the level is the first thing that is done when you invoke : `log.info(myMsg);` In fact, you could even be slower If you use  `if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {log.info(myMsg);}` and that the log level matches often as you do what the logger api already does for you (the check) and as the log level matches, the check is still done by the logger.  Now if you think that you log too much called methods, just remove these logs if these are not helpful.

Comment: So you are log.info, log.debug, log.trace, log.warn... all have guard conditions inside them ? If so, can you show me where this repo https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j I can see that?

Comment: Exactly. Otherwise, how the logger can know if it has to log or not ?  slf4j is the interface. Check rather the implementation. For example logback or log4j. http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/ch/qos/logback/classic/Logger.java#Logger :  the logback Logger source code. You can see   `public void info(String msg) {
        filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(FQCN, null, Level.INFO, msg, null, null);
    }` where `filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus()` is a private method performing the same type of check as `isInfoEnabled()`.

Comment: what if I am concatenating with exceptions? Since exceptions can be log does it makes sense to do the guarded check? for cases like `log.info("Exception occured: ", exception)`

Comment: It is helpless and it is not a concatenation. You use the method `info(String msg, Throwable t)` that is designed to work in the same way. Please read again my answer. It explains that the single case where it is useful is when you perform concatenation that contains expensive computation. For example      `log_.info("name :" + myPerson.getName() + ", order history :" + myPerson.getOrders());`

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach, even if it works, is pointless. The log method already did this work.

The reason because we use the log guard condition is about string concatenation.

Here is the issue:

```
log.debug("This is the case where " + varToBeChecked);
```

In this case you have to use the guard condition:

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
    log.debug("This is the case where " + varToBeChecked);
}
```

This not only avoids the execution of the log statement, but also the string concatenation, that will be done in the previos example.

So if you have just a fixed string with no concatenation you have no reasons to use the guard condition:

```
log.info("Method starts here");
```

In your proposal, the interface is not protecting you from this issue, so you are going to add complexity without solving the issue.

The solution to this log staff could be a change of the log interface:

```
log.debug("My log message for %s of run", myVarToBeLogged);
```

In this case we could avoids the string concatenation, but I'm not sure it is the same performance of using the guard condition.

Comment: Spot on. Note that Slf4J already has an info() method taking a pattern and arguments: https://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/index.html. The syntax would be `"My log message for {} of run"`, though.

Comment: I think you made a point that I am not avoid String concatenation which can be fixed by changing my methods signatures into `default void logInfo(String... msg)` but the performance however is still pretty bad even with {}. Guard condition gives the best performance so far

Comment: Yes, I wrote it in the last sentence. I mean "it could be" a solution instead of using the guard condition, but I was not sure. I wolk throug this issue a couple of year ago in Javascript. And had the same results: have to use the guard condition. :(

Answer (score 2):

The guard is (should be) primarily used to prevent costly operations when no need arises - just for debugging.

So the following would be the correct pattern:

```
    if (log_.isInfoEnabled()) {
        String meg = String.join("log message: ", f(), g(), h);
        log_.info(msg);
    }

default void logInfo(Supplier<String> messageSupplier) {
    if (log_.isInfoEnabled()) {
        log_.info(messageSupplier.get());
    }
}

logInfo(() -> String.join("log message: ", f(), g(), h));
```

However you risk that this method is used for the simple logging cases, turning it in a costly extra function call `logInfo`, and that lambda.

Answer (score 1):

The logging methods only output values to log when a specific logging level is enabled. The only case where manually checking the logging level makes sense is when creating the message to log is expensive. Say, you have to  retrieve a lazy loaded field from the database or walk through a collection with many items. In that case it makes sense to create an interface to simulate a mixin and use functional programming as in:

```
public interface Logging {

    Logger getLogger();

    default void logInfo(Supplier<String> msg){
        Logger logger = getLogger();
        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()){
            logger.info(msg.get());
        }
    }

}

public class Something implements Logging {

    public static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Something.class);

    @Override
    public Logger getLogger() {
        return LOG;
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        logInfo(this::createExpensiveMessage); 
    }

    private String createExpensiveMessage(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Nobody cares 
        }

        return "Something happened";
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You don't need guards if you use parameterized messages and the parameters are direct references to objects or primitive values.

https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance

This is a parameterized message: `log.debug("Person is {}", person);`

Answer (score 0):

Guards are still needed if logging parameters use some kind of processing to get to the object we want to log. What slf4j deferres is only the call to object's toString() method, but not the computations that are performed to get the object itself. This guard is reasonable to put here:

```
if (log.isdebugEnabled()) {
 log.debug("Value {} is not valid", obj.connectToDBAndRetrieveValue());
}
```

So having a custom log wrapper to encapsulate the guard logic might be handy. And also, it will shift unit testing of this condition from client code to the concrete wrapper class what would be much easier and cleaner to do.

As a side note, actually this kind of wrapper is not needed for INFO level since INFO is usually enabled in production. Unless this is not your case.